# How do I get task force members in Boom Beach?

Tags: boom-beach

I created a new task force, but none of my friends play the game and when I write in the Supercell forums no one is joining either.

Is there another way to get new members?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recruiting is very hard nowadays.

There are currently a few other ways you can try except the official forums:

https://www.reddit.com/r/BoomBeach/

Telegram (App) with this join link: https://telegram.me/joinchat/DLMKqT6-oqwYseYSIO3m4Q (Hopper-Network)

Or the classic "jump-from-tf-to-tf-and-tell-everyone-about-your-tf". This one is a bit mean though. But I did this with "half full" tfs and got some results.

Good luck! :)